# PHP mysqli stmt bind result not getting values

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone tell me what is the problem with this code? I've been trying to get the values from my database for hours and the results are always null.. Except for the username and password.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("aaaaa", "bbbbb", "cccccc", "ddddd");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $id, $full_name, $email, $password, $distance, $average_rating, $home_address, $work_address);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;
    $response["full_name"] = $full_name;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["password"] = $password;
    $response["distance"] = $distance;
    $response["average_rating"] = $average_rating;
    $response["home_address"] = $home_address;
    $response["work_address"] = $work_address;
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

The problem seems to be in the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` line, but I can't figure it out. The order of the variables is correct. I have a connection with the database and everything is OK, but the results are null.

Here's the JSON result:

```
{"success":true,"full_name":null,"email":"aaaaaaaaa","password":"bbbbbbb","distance":null,"average_rating":null,"home_address":null,"work_address":null}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to `echo` the whole thing in the `while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement) { echo ... }` once (just to see what's going on).

I'm not sure, but I think you're overwriting the values in `$response[]`

Comment: If I change `$response["full_name"] = $full_name;` with `$response["full_name"] = "some text"`, I get the some text value in the json response.... So that means that the `$response` value is empty when I am passing it to the `$response["full_name"]`, right? I don't know how to echo in the while, if I try that, I get `success: false` in the json response..

Comment: try to query the specific fields instead of *

Comment: @RST , I've already tried that, nothing is changed..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, I've managed to solve my problem with the code below. I have no idea what was the problem with the previous code. If someone happen to know the solution to that problem, please answer in the comments, I am curious. Note: The code is only for test proposes.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd");

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row["email"]==$email && $row["password"] == $password){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["full_name"] = $row["full_name"];
        $response["email"] = $row["email"];
        $response["password"] = $row["password"];
        $response["distance"] = $row["distance"];
        $response["average_rating"] = $row["average_rating"];
        $response["home_address"] = $row["home_address"];
        $response["work_address"] = $row["work_address"];
        break;
    }
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```